# how to send data from angularJS controler to PHP using Json

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

well i have this problem about sending multi data from JS to PHP, i'm using angularJS. the problem is i can't receive any data, i'm a beginner in this stuff like AngularJS.this my my JS part:

```
var data = {"name":name, "cin":cin, "job":job};

var config = {
        params: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };

    $request = "php/readFromDatabase.php";
    $http.post($request, config).then(function (response) {
        $scope.collectionData = response.data.records;
    });
```

this should be fine and work i have my data as struct (object) the name and cin and job are variables when i click button using angularJS controller this function should be launched and call an PHP file :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

i use those information to look for data in database and then i echo them as JSON format for that i want to use $http.get{} so i can call the response.data.records and not to use the $ajax.{}.
the problem is this $_POST['name'] doesn't work;
even this didn't work:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$name = $request->name;
```

As i said, i'm new here so plz tell me what i'm doing wrong because i didn't find anything that can help me, i tied everything i have found in internet.
hope if someone can help me and thank you in advance.

`Edit :`

this is my JS file:

```
app.controller('shearch_data', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.ShearchFunction = function () {

    var name = " ";
    if ($('#toggle_name').prop('checked') == true)
        name = $('#inputName').val();

    var cin = " ";
    if ($('#toggle_cin').prop('checked') == true)
        cin = $('#inputCIN').val();

    var job = " ";
    if ($('#toggle_job').prop('checked') == true)
        job = $('#inputJob').val();

    var data = {'name': "ffss", 'cin': cin,  'job': job};

    var url = "php/readFromDatabase.php";
    $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
        $scope.collectionData = response.data.records;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert('something went wrong')
    });

};
});
```

my PHP :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$name = $request->name;
$cin = $request->cin;
$job = $request->job;
$output = "";
$output .='{"Name":"'.$name.'",';
$output .='"Job":"'.$job.'",';
$output .='"Cin":"'.$cin.'"}';
$output = '{"records":[' . $output . ']}';
echo($output);
```

this is what i'm trying to do for test, send data from JS to PHP using http.post then i receive it as json, it's jsut for test for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments and config are wrong for `$http.post( url, data, config)`

Remove `params` from config, those are for GET url query string params

EDIT: if all you are setting is the `'Content-Type` header you don't need a config....`application/json` is the default

```
var config = {       
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
};

var url = "php/readFromDatabase.php";
$http.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) {
    $scope.collectionData = response.data.records;
}).catch(function(err){
    alert('Ooops...something went wrong')
});
```

Comment: ok, thank you, now my JS will be like this: 
`var data = {"name": "ffss", "cin": cin, "cid": cid, "job": job, "pl": lp};
 var url = "php/readFromDatabase.php";
        $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
            $scope.collectionData = response.data.records;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            alert('something went wrong')
        });`
no need for `' Content-Type': 'application/json' ` in JS file and PHP file.now, how i catch data in PHP, should i use, `$_POST['name']` or `$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$name = $request->name;`

Comment: what you have in question should work. `$_POST` will be empty when you send as `application/json`

Comment: if you don't mind i do like to send you my both JS and PHP file just to see what the problem could be, because i can't read data in PHP.

Comment: i just want to thank you for your help and by the way i find the mistake,it was my fault, i have 2 function the first is calling the PHP file with no parameters so when he try to get the name he find nothing, i don't know how i didn't see that, i just forget about it , lol, my bad, and thanks again ;) it works now i had to pass anything or i will just use isset i guess just to make sure